# paly videos using php

Tags: php, video, playback

i just  written  code for play videos 
like this 
$vid was the video file name where the videos are in www\videos folder.
read the content in the folder using the

```
<video src='videos/$vid'> it is working
```

same as  i just try to play videos in some drive like g:\videos folder
$path='G:\videos\';
$video is video file name in that folder

here i written code like this `<video src='$path\$video'`

please tell me any solution for this

thank u

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `G:\videos` is not a valid html path.  Instead do this.

**PHP**

```
$path = 'file:///G:\videos';
$vid = 'filename.mp4';
```

**HTML**

```
<video src='<?="$path\$vid"?>'>
```